# How to make a square shaped RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I want to draw a chessboard image into the background of a RelativeLayout.

I am testing this in portrait mode (vertical).

This is a piece of my code:

```
device_xdpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().xdpi;
device_ydpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().ydpi;
```

What I would like to do is: taking the dpi size of the shorter edge (the upper edge in portrait mode) and make the the RelativeLayout's height equal to it.

I am trying this:

```
chessBoardLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chessBoardLayout);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) device_xdpi);
            chessBoardLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But it is not working.

How do I convert the device_xdpi into the correct dp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since device_xdpi is in pixels this should work

```
public static int convertPixelsToDp(float px, Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    int dp = (int)(px / (metrics.densityDpi / 160f));
    return dp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [constructor you're using](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html#ViewGroup.LayoutParams%28int,%20int%29) takes *pixels*, not dp. That said, you can get the size of the shortest edge without any dp/pixel conversion:

- Set both dimensions of your layout to `MATCH_PARENT` in your XML.
- Use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on your RelativeLayout once it's measured
- Get the smaller of the two and set both width/height in your new LayoutParams